# How do i remove HeaderButton JQGrid

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

Am setting the caption for the JQGrid and headerbutton appears; and how can remove this?  Just need title to my grid. Headerbutton is to collapse/expand; but i don't need that.

```
<a class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton" href="javascript:void(0)" role="link
style="right: 0px;">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the corresponding jqGrid option

```
hidegrid: false
```

Comment: I tried and i lost the caption :(  It looks like when caption = "" then hidegrid works.  I need caption

Comment: `hidegrid` does not affect the caption - I use this option all the time to suppress the collapse/expand button and have not had a problem with captions disappearing.

Comment: @Oleg, @Justin; thanks it's working with hidegrid:false; I think i had someother issue with grid when i tried hidegrid:false.

Answer (score 0):

hidegrid: false; worked.
I have gone little long route to get the same behavior.

```
$('#results_div  div').find('.HeaderButton').hide();
```